# How to connect to PEAP enterprise wifi networks that has no inner authentication

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

Our company has a network that uses PEAP network with no inner authentication. However Ubuntu has no option for 'none'. I have read on a few other forums that changing `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/$SSID` with `phase2-auth='none'` but this does not work so I am sure it's invalid.

Is there any workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, I found an answer months after asking this.

I ticked the box:

> No CA certificate is required

See screenshot for the settings.

[image: Editing Wi-Fi settings]